# Accessing registry in C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I try to access a specific registry key that i know exist. I use this way:

```
 RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine; 
 RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(KeyName,false);
```

if i replace 'KeyName' with *@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"*, for example,  it works fine. 
 
if i try any other path that i copy pasted from regedit for exmple *@"SOFTWARE\ATI Technologies\Install\South Bridge\ATI_AHCI_RAID"* it return null.
I'm workiung on win7 64-bit with an x86 program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows 64-bit (Windows 2003+, XP and later 64-bit) there is a *transparent* registry redirection happening to provide separate logical views for 32-bit and 64-bit registry calls.

Read the link below for more information; it is important information to know.

> The registry redirector isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by
>   providing separate logical views of certain portions of the registry
>   on WOW64. The registry redirector intercepts 32-bit and 64-bit
>   registry calls to their respective logical registry views and maps
>   them to the corresponding physical registry location. The redirection
>   process is **transparent** to the application. Therefore, a 32-bit
>   application can access registry data as if it were running on 32-bit
>   Windows even if the data is stored in a different location on 64-bit
>   Windows.

[MSDN Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)